# Particle in a box momentum wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Why is the momentum wave function of a particle in a box equal to this expression? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Momentum_wave_function

Surely the Fourier transform of a sine wave amounts to two dirac deltas either side of zero. What is the cause of this additional complexity?

Comment: The wavefunction is not a sine wave. It's the product of a sine wave and a top hat function that specifies the width of the box. So the Fourier transform is the convolution of the FT of a sine wave (i.e. a delta) and the FT of the top hat function (i.e. a sinc).

Answer (score -1):

The energy eigenfunction in the one-dimensional box looks like
$$\phi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left( \frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$
which is a square integrable as in should be so that $\phi_n(x)\in l_2$ that suggest that the $\tilde{\phi}_n(p)$ must be square integrable too which is fourier transform of $\phi_n(x)$.

OP's suggestion that $\tilde{\phi}_n(p) $ should be dirac delta function knock down as dirac delta in no in $l_2$.

As suggested in the comment $\phi_n(x)$ is not a sin wave. The only way to settle this is to actually find out the Fourier transform of the $\phi_n(x)$.